# Save CvSeq to an array

Tags: opencv

I am a bit lost in OpenCV docs, I would like to save CvSeq returned by cvFindContours to an array, from what I understand it will return a seq of CvContour s but i couldn't find what it contains? which parts of it should I save to that later I can later I can iterate through it and say call cvBoundingRect etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A CvContour is a struct with the same fields as a CvSeq, plus a few others, the most important of which is a CvRect rect (see include/opencv/cxtypes.h). So it really boils down to what a CvSeq is.

There is a file called *opencv.pdf* that comes with the OpenCV sources, and in p. 138 (for OpenCV 2.1) it says that CvSeq is defined as follows:

```
#define CV_SEQUENCE\_FIELDS()
    int flags; /* micsellaneous flags */ \
    int header_size; /* size of sequence header */ \
    struct CvSeq* h_prev; /* previous sequence */ \
    struct CvSeq* h_next; /* next sequence */ \
    struct CvSeq* v_prev; /* 2nd previous sequence */ \
    struct CvSeq* v_next; /* 2nd next sequence */ \
    int total; /* total number of elements */ \
    int elem_size;/* size of sequence element in bytes */ \
    char* block_max;/* maximal bound of the last block */ \
    char* ptr; /* current write pointer */ \
    int delta_elems; /* how many elements allocated when the sequence grows
    (sequence granularity) */ \
    CvMemStorage* storage; /* where the seq is stored */ \
    CvSeqBlock* free_blocks; /* free blocks list */ \
    CvSeqBlock* first; /* pointer to the first sequence block */

typedef struct CvSeq
{
    CV_SEQUENCE_FIELDS()
} CvSeq;
```

Let's say you call cvFindContours like this:

```
cvFindContours(img, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
```

, where `contours` will be pointing to the first contour after calling `cvFindContours`. If you want to get its bounding rectangle, you simply pass it to `cvBoundingRect`. The next contour in the sequence can be accessed through `contours->h_next`. In the case of contour trees, that is, when a contour can be inside another contour in the image, you can access the first inner contour of the current contour through `contours->v_next`. The next inner contour, if it exists, would be `contours->v_next->h_next`, and so forth.

If you want to convert a sequence to an array you can use [`cvCvtSeqToArray`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_dynamic_structures.html?highlight=cvcvtseqtoarray#cvCvtSeqToArray).

You can also use the C++ interface starting from OpenCV 2.0 which seems to be nicer to use. For instance, the `CvSeq** contours` parameter to `cvFindContours` becomes `vector<vector<Point> >& contours`.