# opencv ios cvseq storage

Tags: objective-c, ios, opencv, nsmutabledictionary

I am intending to pre-load all the images that I have stored inside application. Pre-loading of images involves:

1. Read images from bundle.
2. Extract object descriptors using cvExtractSurf from opencv framework.
3. Store IPLImage with corresponding object descriptors and keypoints.

I am having an issue in creating a dictionary containing CvSeq* keys and CvSeq* descs.
Please suggest how to store these values in NSMutableDictionary.

```
-(void) preloadImages:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary{
NSArray *d = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);


for( int i=0;i<[d count];i++){
    NSString *searchForMe = @"myapp.app/1";
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[d objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSRange range = [s rangeOfString:searchForMe];
    if( range.location != NSNotFound ){
        NSMutableDictionary *surfDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSString *substring = [s substringFromIndex:range.location];
        substring = [substring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"myapp.app/" withString:@""];
        UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:substring];
        IplImage *iplTestImage = [OpenCVUtilities CreateGRAYIplImageFromUIImage:testImage];

        CvSeq *keys = 0 ;
        CvSeq *descs = 0;
        cvExtractSURF( iplTestImage, 0, &keys, &descs, storage, params );

        [surfDict setObject:(id)testImage forKey:@"uiImage"];


        NSLog(@"Image name : %@", substring);
        [dictionary setObject:surfDict forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        [dictionary setObject:(NSObject *)keys forKey:@"keys"]; // error here
        [dictionary setObject:(NSObject *)descs forKey:@"descs"]; // error here
        [surfDict release];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719661/save-cvseq-to-an-array) link. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that has an instance variable of type cvseq, add your cvseq to the object, and add that class to the dictionary.